# Which type of 100nF capacitor is best for 78xx regulator output?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, ceramic, tantalum

I use 78L12 or similar voltage regulators in a few power supplies. I use them in their basic setup, see the picture:

[image: 78Lxx circuit]

This diagram is common for all 78xx and 78Lxx regulators. It says that output capacitor should be 100nF. I am able to obtain these 100nF capacitors either **ceramic**, or **tantalum**, or **film** for almost the same price (near to nothing) so I'd like to know which type of capacitor is the best for this particular case.

Note: I know that a tantalum cap is recommended for SMPS output, but 78xx isn't switched-mode.

Comment: The correct capacitor in this situation is what you have on hand/is cheapest. The 78** series regulators are very tolerant of input and output capacitors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is little point to ever use a tantalum when a ceramic is available for the same cost.

Actually, I'd use a 1µF ceramic on the output and a 10µF ceramic on the input.  The 7805 will be plenty stable with those, and that will help with transcient response.

The reason you see 100nF (let's not use ".1µF" baby talk) a lot is for historical reasons.  Back in neolithic times when a caveman first carved a 7805 from a chunk of silicon, that was about the limit of cheap and available ceramic caps.

Comment: I'm curious, why is it baby talk to call it 100nF? :)

Comment: @avakar You got it wrong: "let's not use baby talk and call it .1µF"

Comment: @avakar: It isn't.  I'll edit my answer to make this more clear.  As I said, baby talk is ".1uF", "10000pF", and the like.  In engineering we use the proper units prefix so that there are always 1-3 digits left of the decimal point.

Comment: @avakar I'm guessing some people use ".1µF" instead of "100nF" because they're not confident with their unit conversion skills..

Comment: @OlinLathrop, ah, yes, I misunderstood, it makes sense now. :)

Comment: Do you recommend the same big values (i.e. 10µF and 1µF) even for 78Lxx regulators which are limited to 0.1A current?

Comment: @Al Kepp: Why not?  They aren't physically bigger or cost more, and they still have plenty high enough frequency response.

Comment: @olin, you might be confusing engineering with some other discipline (Physics? Accounting?). My experience is in engineering most people either use units that are conventional in certain circumstances (like naming capacitors in pF or uF but not nF) or use the units that make a calculation most convenient (like converting all units to MKS before starting to calculate).

Comment: @Olin: Not to nitpick, but shouldn't it be written 100 nF (with a space) rather than 100nF? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-0

Comment: @m.Alin: It would be strange if someone can understand micro but not nano.  If so, then they definitely need to take the 5 minutes to look at a chart and learn the common prefixes from pico to Giga at least.  Anyone that can't handle that has no business talking about electronics or most all engineering disciplines.  This is not a hard concept.

Comment: @Jonny: You are nitpicking, but you're also right.  There is supposed to be a space there.  Sometimes it seems clearer to leave it off, but you're right, that's technically incorrect.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop Can you please elaborate a bit on why it's better to use ceramics than tantalum capacitors? I for example can't (easily) obtain big ceramics (as in bigger that 100 nF), but tantalum capacitors are available to me in that range.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Ceramic capacitors are available in Serbia just like everywhere else.  I have a lot of stuff manufactured in Serbia (Novi Sad) and they've never complained about not being able to get ceramic caps.  Tantalum have poorer frequency response, are unipolar, higher leakage, and cost more than ceramic.  However, if you have them on hand for some reason go ahead and use them.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop Both of those information are good to have! It could be that my big list is missing some distributors, so I'll have to fix that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I call bullshit on the "Baby Talk" comment. If it were true, you'd hear mechanical engineering types quoting length in decimeters, or any of the many other SI prefixes that languish unused.

Comment: Really, what it boils down to is that the spacing of SI prefixes at intervals of 1,000 is arbitrary. Using intervals of 1,000,000 (e.g. F, uF, pF) makes just as much sense. Furthermore, It actually tents to *simplify* the mathematics, as you spend less time converting from one unit to another (sure unit conversion is easy, but why add more work when it's **not needed**?). It also makes situations where the unit is not labeled easier to guess. Frankly, I (personally) think that mF and nF are better off unused.

Comment: @Fake: Spacing the prefixes at multiples of 1000 is a *convention*.  It's the standard for how it's done.  The reason for not using 10^6 is that this causes too many digits floating around that may not be significant.  And, it's no work at all to shift "convert" since it's just shifting a decimal point around.  You'd have to "convert" a 5 digit value to something else just as likely.

Comment: @OlinLathrop The 10 µF ceramics I can find are all really expensive (1 µF are cheap). Should I go for a 2.2 µF ceramic in that case or would I do better with a 10 µF tantalum cap?

Comment: Why not using a Film Capacitor? Isn't it better than ceramic?

Answer (score 3):

I use ceramic capacitors in both positions, as do most people, and don't have any problems.